# exact sum of series $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!} $ using $e^x$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to find the exact sum of $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!} $ using $e^x$

Here's what I tried:
$$
e^1=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!} = e^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-\frac{1}{2})^n=e^1\frac{2}{3}
$$

But according to wolframalpha, it should equal $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^1}}$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not the first time I see something like $$ f(x) = f\cdot x $$ :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\implies e^{-1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!}$$

Note the factorial in the denominator, which is absent in the OP.  Moreover,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!}\ne\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!} \neq \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!} \right) \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-\frac{1}{2})^n\right)$$
which is what you tried to use.

Instead, plug in $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ in the Taylor series of $e^x$.